# Can't install Flash Player on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, adobe-flash

I tried to install the flashplugin-nonfree on Debian Jessie (testing) today. However, when I tr running `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`, I get `E: Unable to locate package flashplugin-nonfree`. The same happens with Aptitude.

My sources.list:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main

# testing-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing-updates main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing-backports main contrib non-free
```

By the way, I use Chromium.

Comment: Please include the output of `apt-cache policy flashplugin-nonfree` in your question.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `N: Unable to locate package flashplugin-nonfree`

Comment: What arch? Try a different mirror, perhaps?

Comment: Note that this installer is only available for `i386` and `amd64`. http://ftp.tw.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/f/flashplugin-nonfree/

Comment: How else would I install it then?

Comment: What arch, please?

Comment: @FaheemMitha x86_64.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know what is going on. When you enter http://http.debian.net into your browser, what site do you actually go to? And is this the same site as apt uses?

Comment: Also, can you include the output of `apt-cache policy`? And have you run `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This might be better as a comment, but as an answer is better formatted)

Comment every line in the `sources.list` file, but:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Then, run `aptitude update && aptitude search flashplugin-nonfree` and share the results.

It should find the following packages:

- https://packages.debian.org/jessie/flashplugin-nonfree

In the worst case scenario, you can download the package from the above link and install it through a `dpkg -i <package.deb>` command...  If you have to deal with dependencies, then that's a different story - good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try this for Firefox/Iceweasel:

1: Get the [Adobe Flash Player .tar.gz](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer)

2: Extract it

3: Open a terminal

4: `cd` to the extracted folder

5: run `sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`

It works for me :-)

Thanks to https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?977-Install-Flash-Player-for-Iceweasel-Firefox-in-3-Simple-Steps

Comment: you should also mention where to extract the file...

Answer (score 1):

> By the way, I use Chromium.

From https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer

> Unsupported browsers:
>
> Chromium

For Chrome/Chromium you should use https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer

> Pepper Flash Player is maintained by Google, and is newer than Adobe Flash layer. Adobe currently still provides security fixes for Adobe Flash Player. Google provides newer features in Pepper Flash Player. Pepper Flash Player can currently only be used with Chromium (and with Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

At the end of each line add the words contrib non-free as follows:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Reference: https://www.lifewire.com/get-flash-to-work-iceweasel-debian-2202059